# How do you use jquery to allow a user to choose site preference and then redirect to that page/site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have one domain that needs multiple home pages and I would like to have the visitor select their preference and have that preference set in a cookie using JQuery. I have no access to code on the site, so this needs to be done using jQuery or Javascript. I'm not a programmer but I can piece things together if I have a headstart.

More details: 
    www.domain.com/home
    www.domain.com/home2
    www.domain.com/home3

```
User makes a choice from the above in a pulldown menu

Cookie is set marking their home page preference

User is redirected to their specific choice

Next time they visit www.domain.com the cookie is read and they are redirected to their preference

If no cookie exists, redirect to root or /home
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do if you have "no access to code on the site" and yet "have one domain", but you might find [this jQuery cookie library](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) useful.

As for the redirect bit, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript).

Comment: What I mean by 'no access to code' is-- we cannot add .asp/.php, etc. We have a way to add javascript/css to specific pages but that is it. I'll check out the links you sent.